# How to import rain data for purposes of upload to Wunderground

Tags: python, import

I have a program that counts pulses (Hall effect sensor) on a rain gauge to measure precipitation.  It runs continuously and counts a number of pulses every 5 minutes that then translates into a rain amount.  After an hour (12 - 5min. measurements, I add the total and  this is the hourly rainfall. I have structure this program so that it drops the oldest measurement and adds the new one each 5 minutes after an hour, and so I have a running hourly rain output, termed "totalrainlasthour".

My problem is that I want to upload this data to weather underground using a separate program that includes other data such as wind speed, temp, etc. This upload takes place every 5 minutes.  I want to include the current value of "totalrainlasthour", and use it in the upload.

I tried  a "from import" command but the more I read, that doesn't look like it would work.

```
from rainmodule import totalrainlasthour
print totalrainlasthour
```

Is there a way can I pull in the current value of a variable from a separate program?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no good way for a python script that just starts up to access the values from inside an already-running Python instance. However, there are a few workarounds that you can try.

If it's acceptable for your weather uploading script to be running constantly, you could structure it to look something like this:

```
import time

import rainmodule
import windmodule
# etc

def start():
    # instantiate classes so you can keep track of state
    rain = rainmodule.RainCollection()
    wind = windmodule.WindCollection()
    # etc

    prev_time = time.time()

    while True:
        rain.loop()
        wind.loop()
        # etc


        now = time.time()
        if now - prev_time > (60*60*5):
            prev_time = now

            totalrainlasthour = rain.totalrainlasthour
            winddata = wind.data
            # upload code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

This method assumes that every one of your data collection modules can be modified to run iteratively within a "master" `while` loop.

If you can't wrangle your code to fit this format, (or the `loop` methods for some modules take a long time to execute) then you could perhaps launch each of your modules as a process using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) or [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) modules, and communicate using some synchronized data structure or a queue.

---

An alternative solution might be to create a database of some sort (Python comes bundled with [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), which could work), and have each of the scripts write to that database. That way, any arbitrary script could run and grab what it needs to from the database without having to tie in to the other data collection modules.

The only potential issue with using sqlite is that since it's lightweight, it supports only [one writer](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) at a time, so if you're making a huge amount of changes and additions to the database, it may end up being a bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick response to my question.  I am a python neophyte and so I have been using the last few days to digest your suggestions and try different options.  I can't use the approach you described because my rainsensor gathers data over an hour whereas my wind sensor takes 5 minutes, and my temp and humidity sensors are essentially instantaneous.  To run these modules in sequence would delay upload for an hour+.  I think the answer is in multiprocessing or multithreading as you suggested.  That way, I can have data from the different modules being created at their own speed.